# ASP.Net Generic Localization does not work while switching language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, custom-attributes

I implemented localization with `DisplayName` and `Required` attributes, it works fine with `DisplayName` when I switch from English to Arabic language but for Required attribute - It is not getting updated with Arabic error message.

Below is the way I implemented and my code below:

**DisplaName - Works fine in both language switching..**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Event)]
    public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
    {
        private ResourceUtils.Key _resourceKey;

        public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(ResourceUtils.Key resourceKey)
            : base()
        {
            _resourceKey = resourceKey;
        }

        public override string DisplayName
        {
            get
            {
                return ResourceUtils.GetDisplayName(_resourceKey);
            }
        }
    }
```

**It works fine, but only once - while switching from one language to another, it keeps old message of previous language after switching.. ErrorMessage doesn't get updated..**

```
public class RequiredLocalizedAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public RequiredLocalizedAttribute(ResourceUtils.Key resourceKey)
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = ResourceUtils.GetDisplayName(resourceKey);
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredLocalizedAttribute), typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
```

Modal code.

```
[LocalizedDisplayName(ResourceUtils.Key.Number)]
[RequiredLocalized(ResourceUtils.Key.NumberMessage)]
public int Number { get; set; }
```

What should I do? It is not working while switching language for ErrorMessage - DisplayName gets updated successfully while language switch.

Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't use `DisplayName` and  `Required` attributes itself? They already support localization. [Visit this great post](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Hi Sam, I am using but it seems verbos - I have to write localization for each property to fetch and I am fetching resources from db.. see this post why I am not using it..     http://www.softwareisinthedetails.com/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-validation-attributes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom `required` attribute initialized just one time, not per request. And you set your error message in constructor. Therefore your error message is not updated. 
Consider write custom factory for it. Or simply update your message in `FormatErrorMessage` method:

```
public class RequiredLocalizedAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    ResourceUtils.ResourceKey _resourceKey;
    public RequiredLocalizedAttribute(ResourceUtils.ResourceKey resourceKey)
    {
        this._resourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = ResourceUtils.GetDisplayName(resourceKey);
        return base.FormatErrorMessage(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: >> Application_Start()
                 DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredLocalizedAttribute), typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
            ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();

Comment: No effect. It seems something wierd, caching?

Comment: You right it is not about caching. but I have found problem. see updated answer.

Comment: New error.. " Either ErrorMessageString or ErrorMessageResourceName must be set, but not both. "

Comment: Why and where you set  `ErrorMessageResourceName` ?

Comment: "fieldName" in FormatErrorMessage will be obsolate without use.

Comment: If you want keep formatting stuff you can write my code. but if you think you don't need formatting your code also good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84307/discussion-between-k-s-and-sam-farajpour-ghamari).